# buffer overflow when trying to run a script

Tags: linux

I'm trying to run a file.

```
# !/usr/bin/en sh
CAFFEROOT=/root/caffe
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CAFFEROOT/build/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./app --ip 1.1.0.0:8887 --workers 1 --timeout 20
```

but i get this error message.

```
root@1b311ba128b3:~/sharedfolder/code# sh run.sh 
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./app terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7329f)[0x7f58d08bd29f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f58d095887c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10d750)[0x7f58d0957750]
./app[0x43dcfb]
./app[0x43e15c]
./app[0x40cdcf]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f58d086bf45]
./app[0x40d63f]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-004c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 5513936                                /root/sharedfolder/code/app
006c6000-006c7000 r--p 000c6000 08:12 5513936                              /root/sharedfolder/code/app
006c7000-006c8000 rw-p 000c7000 08:12 5513936                            /root/sharedfolder/code/app
006c8000-006c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0187d000-018fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                      [heap]
```

Im not sure what this means? Any ideas as to how i may approach this might be helpful.Thanks in advance

Comment: `./app terminated` The buffer overflow is within the app not within the script. You need to debug the application or  rewrite the application not to segfault. You can use `dbg` or `strace` or `valgrind` or similar utilities to debug your application.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The app file is a little lengthy, let me try debugging this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdb would be my goto tool for this. Something like

```
# !/usr/bin/en sh
CAFFEROOT=/root/caffe
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CAFFEROOT/build/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH gdb ./app --ip 1.1.0.0:8887 --workers 1 --timeout 20
```

... then

```
run
```

The following is a nice trick to see the lines being executed right up until the segfault:

Run with gdb as above, then:

```
set logging on
break main
run
while 1
step
end
```

... the trace is then in `gdb.txt`

Comment: Thanks let me check this.